# cannot use Ionic DevApp with React

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-devapp

Since Ionic React [does not](https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/overview) support Cordova, is it possible to use Ionic DevApp to view Ionic App on mobile device? If Ionic DevApp is not supported with React based project, any suggestions on how to view and test Ionic Apps on a mobile device without really publishing the app?

Comment: To use native plugins with Ionic react, they are advising to use Capacitor framework https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/cordova/ check this in the official documentation : https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/overview#native-tooling #Native tooling section

Comment: Yes, thats right and thats where the problem is. I can use capacitor with xcode to test the app on iPhone however it is time consuming and hard to debug apps. Ionic DevApp makes it easy to view and test apps.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running into the same issue. There seems to be no documentation from the Ionic team on this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please note that this cannot be an answer. You can post this note as a comment.